# Share intent between classes

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, intentfilter, android-pendingintent

I am developing an application that reads and receives Android NFC tags,
in particular I want to spend the intent NFC.NDEF_DISCOVERED to an activity that manages. Activity A receive a NDEFMessage and call Activity B that performs the operation on NDEF message.
How I can do?
I read the documentation about the Android Intent, but I am not clear.
So, please, do not answer me "read the documentation Android".

Comment: From what I can tell, you should be setting a Handler to look for Intents coming from NFC. Also, you should be adding the `<intent-filter>` in your Manifest as well. And although you said not to answer with "read the documentation", I'm going to have to link it anyway. I always managed to learn something new every time I go through the documentation. While you won't always get your answer, it'll help you get close. [Android - NFC](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html)

Comment: Please be more specific about what "Class A" and "Class B" actually are. I am assuming that "Class A" is really an `Activity`, but that is just an educated guess. We need to know what these classes are to give you accurate advice.

Comment: I have already stated the intent filter for nfcdescover in my manifest.xml in the declaration of Activity B. The point is that I have to transfer the NFC intent received by activity A in the Activity B.
THX
THX

Comment: thanks CommonsWare for the clarification. Class is for activity